# What is the proper way to get a char input(using Scanner) inside a loop in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a simple calculator program where a user can opt to do an operation and enter the numbers as long as he/she wishes to.

I just have problem because whenever I would reach inside my loop and ask the user if he/she want to continue and whenever I would run the program, I would have an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Scanner myInput=new Scanner(System.in);

```
System.out.print("Do you have numbers to compute?");
ans=myInput.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

while ((ans=='Y')||(ans=='y'))
{
    //get the numbers
    //provide the menu
    //get the user's choice

    switch (calc)
    {
        case 1: out.println("Sum is: " +(num1+num2)); break;
        case 2: out.println("Difference is: " +(num1-num2)); break;
        case 3: out.println("Product is: " +(num1*num2)); break;
        case 4: out.println("Quotient is: " +(num1/num2)); break;
        case 5: out.println("Modulo is is: " +(num1%num2)); break;
        case 6: out.println("Sum is: " +(num1+num2));
                    out.println("Difference is: " +(num1-num2));
                    out.println("Product is: " +(num1*num2));
                    out.println("Quotient is: " +(num1/num2));
                    out.println("Modulo is is: " +(num1%num2)); break;
                    default: out.println("Invalid."); break;
    }
       out.println("Compute another?");
       ans=myInput.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
}
```

May I humbly ask what can I do with this program so that it will ask again for the user's input whether to continue or not? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's best to try and post some code, even badly formatted, so we can know how to best help you. If it's homework please add the homework tag too.

Comment: Hello Tudor, I was able to insert the code in this post.

Comment: Ok, now in which line of this code do you get NullPointerException?

Comment: after the out.println("Compute another?"); part

Comment: Does findIneLine() return null if the String is not found? (Just a guess) Have you tried to debug your code in a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is being thrown as `Scanner.findInLine()` can return null if it does not find the requested String/Pattern. The code invokes the method `charAt(0)` on the null String. Changing the code to the following will resolve this:

```
Scanner myInput=new Scanner(System.in);
char ans;

System.out.print("Do you have numbers to compute?");
ans=myInput.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

while ((ans=='Y')||(ans=='y'))
{
    // Code omitted

    System.out.print("Compute another?");
    myInput.nextLine();
    String s = myInput.findInLine(".");
    ans = (null == s) ? 'n' : s.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in this palce, best way is to use do-while

```
do{
System.out.print("Do you have numbers to compute?");
ans=myInput.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
//
//
//

}while ((ans=='Y')||(ans=='y'));
```

This will keep asking till the user's answer is 'Y' or 'y'.

I hope you can take care of other thing.

for using while loop.

```
System.out.print("Do you have numbers to compute?");
char ans=myInput.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

while((ans=='Y')||(ans=='y')){
//
//
//
System.out.print("Do you have numbers to compute?");
ans=myInput.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a while loop in this case even if I have a statement of asking the user if there is any computation to be done?

Comment: yes you can use.. for that you should ask the question once before starting the loop and then before ending the loop, updating the code.